# C# Calling public static task from another project within same solution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, call

I have the below code in one project of my solution:

This is my program with my method, an async HTTP POST :

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly NLog.Logger _log_ = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //... initializing MyThing with properties and values for the method arguments, and then I call the method
        //and it works.

        DoHttpPostAsync(MyThing.BaseURL, MyThing.Headers, MyThing.Body, HttpMethod.Post).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

        public async static Task DoHttpPostAsync(Uri HTTPaddress, cHeaders cconsHeaders, cBody ccons, HttpMethod Method)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);

                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, HTTPaddress))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = HTTPaddress;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                    //....
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.TargetSite + "\r\n" + e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and from another project, I want to call this task. Although I can call it in my first project, it doesn't show in the other project (dependency is working). I do have the 'using..' and I do see all properties and assign values etc and when I try to call the method, it is simply not there (in intellisense drop-down. How do I call this method from my other project?
All help appreciated..

Note:
This is the 'other' project, calling code..

```
using psd2c = <the initial project name>;
//...

public class Testing
{
    public void ACreateSome()
    {
        psd2c.PCns PDS2ewC = new psd2c.PCns();

        PDS2ewC.BaseURL = new System.Uri("http://192.xxx.yyy.zzz:8678/some/path/here/");

        PDS2ewC.Body.access.AllPd2 = "allAccounts";
        PDS2ewC.Body.access.AvailableAccounts = "YES";

        PDS2ewC.Body.CombinedServiceIndicator = false;
        PDS2ewC.Body.FrequencyPerDay = 10;
        PDS2ewC.Body.ValidUntil = "2020-12-31";

        PDS2ewC.Headers.CorrID = "5D1D38...";
        PDS2ewC.Headers.RequestID = "53JD98XD-8...";
        PDS2ewC.Headers.CToken = "abc... ...xyz";

        PDS2ewC.DoHttpPostAsync(... ...etc);    //the async in the other proj: Not recognised at all...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not static?

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions - parameter names of `httpAddress` and and `method` instead of `HTTPAddress` and `Method`, and class names without a `c` prefix.

Comment: [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: @JonSkeet : very good point, I will follow your advice asap. As far as the question concern, although public static, I do in *another* project a public class ABC and within I have a method, say public void Something(), where I instantiate and add parameters. When I try to call this task, is simply not there...

Comment: @Fildor: Thank you for the comment and for the link - I am novice so the link you provide has a huge amount of helpful information that I would need to study. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind adding that calling code? (or "trying to call", I should write)

Comment: @Fildor: Thanks for helping, caller (another project)
`using psd2c = PSD2_CreateCn;
//...

public class Testing
{
 public void DoCns()
 {
  psd2c.PCns PDS2ewC = new psd2c.PCns();

  PDS2ewC.BaseURL = new System.Uri("http://192.xxx.yyy.zzz:8678/some/path/here/");

  PDS2ewC.Body.access.AllPd2 = "ALL";
  PDS2ewC.Body.access.AvailableAccounts = "YES";

//...
  PDS2ewC.Headers.CorrID = "5D1D38...";
  PDS2ewC.Headers.RequestID = "53JD98...";
  PDS2ewC.Headers.CToken = "abc... ...xyz";

  PDS2ewC.CreateConsent(); //Not recognised at all...
 }
}`

Comment: Please edit the code into your question, rather than using comments for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies, you're absolutely right, I thought it would appear better in comments but obviously.. /I will try to edit the question.

Comment: Is the method static or not? The method you showed is not static.... Can you post the class that contains the method with the actual method in it?  If the method is static you would call it like this psd2c.PCns.DoHttpPostAsync(.....  NOT using the instance variable.  So we really need to know if the method is static or not.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] here. There's a lot we can't tell about this code.

Comment: @Darkonekt Thank you for helping on this.. There is no method, it is a project with the first part of code in it, the public async Task DoHttpPostAsync on which I provide the arguments (and compiles and runs) and a second project (dependencies ok) where I try to call the task (PDS2ewC.DoHttpPostAsync(... ...etc);) and doesn't work..

Comment: The method called DoHttpPostAsync is inside a class we need to see the code for that class

Comment: I think maybe your method is inside a diffeerent class.  Please post the code the PCns class

Comment: The public class Program has only the static void Main(string[] args) empty and and then follows the public async Task DoHttpPostAsync as you see exactly in the code in first code box.
The second project has only the Main with Testing tst = new Testing(); in one line and tst.ACreateSome(); and that's it..

Comment: Please post the PCns class

Comment: Also if the "public async Task DoHttpPostAsync" is inside the Program class why are you trying to call it from the PCns class?

Comment: @Darkonekt You are right on your observation: I try to call it from another project because some additional logic is to be added and the "initial" project will only have the properties necessary for the call and this task (or possibly more async tasks)

Comment: Actually it all comes down to this: if we have a project P(A) with a public async static Task (doing a HTTP post, if that makes a difference) in our program class - not in Main - and we have another project P(B), can we call this Task (assuming correct arguments are being passed to it) ?

Comment: Since the method "public async static Task DoHttpPostAsync(" is NOT part of the PCns class you will not be able to call it from that class.... You will have to do something like "Program.DoHttpPostAsync" to call it.

Comment: @Darkonekt Thank you, I will try it!